# How do you implement mutual casts?

Tags: c++, typecasting-operator

Say you have two struct types, one with `int` members and one with `float`.

```
struct i { 
    int a, b; 
    i(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}
};

struct f { 
    float a, b;
    f(float a, float b): a(a), b(b) {}
};
```

We want to define two cast operators, from `i` to `f` and conversely. If we try to do it by operator overloading

```
struct i { 
    int a, b; 
    i(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}
    operator f() const { return f(a, b); };
};

struct f { 
    float a, b;
    f(float a, float b): a(a), b(b) {}
    operator i() const { return i(a, b); };
};
```

we run in a problem of order of declaration, because `i` needs to know `f` and `f` needs to know `i`. Furthermore, the cast operators must be declared inside the classes. A forward declaration of `f` doesn't work.

Is there a solution ?

Comment: Your code has many syntax errors.  If you fix them, forward declaration works.

Comment: The cast operator has to return the type which it casts to not some other one... so it is not int() but i() instead!

Comment: I have now fixed the typos.  The problem is "`use of undefined type 'f'`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forward declaration works fine:

```
struct i;
struct f;

struct i
{
    int a, b; 
    i(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}
    operator f() const;
};

struct f
{
    float a, b;
    f(float a, float b): a(a), b(b) {}
    explicit operator i() const;
};

i::operator f() const { return f(a, b); }
f::operator i() const { return i(a, b); }
```

Comment: I see, you have to split declaration/definition.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Yes, that's true for all mutually-dependent types.  Conversions are not special.

Comment: BTW: f::operator i() it is not needed to split as i is known at this point

Comment: @Klaus: If you mean "is not required", that's true.  But "must not" means "is not allowed" -- it is not the negation of "must".

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yep! Language problem as in german it has a different meaning :-) Sorry!

Comment: If I want to make sure that the cast methods are inlined, I assume that I need to qualify the definitions as such ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: No! Compilers are smart enough to know when inlining is best optimization option. You only have to use inline if a definition is in header file out of class scope to avoid a linker error cuase of multiple definitions.  The meaning of the keyword to hint the compiler to inline the code into the callers context is fully obsolete. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

Comment: @Klaus: But you have to put the definition into a header file to give the compiler a chance to inline it (unless you have whole program optimization aka link-time code generation).

Comment: @BenVoigt: "that the cast methods are inlined, I assume that I need to qualify the definitions as such". Thats not true! As long as they are in the header and the header is only used once, everything is ok. To make the header includeable multiple times, the operators must be marked "inline", yes. But this has nothing to with the optimization itself. I want to clarify that "inline" is not longer a hint for the compiler for optimization. It is only to avoid linker errors!

Comment: @Klaus: Right, it's making the definition visible that encourages the compiler to perform inlining, not the `inline` keyword.  That scenario usually causes a multiple definition error, which the `inline` keyword will fix.